# How can I know when a YouTube video was deleted?

Tags: youtube

How can I know the date or time for when a YouTube video has been deleted?

[image: This video had been removed]

Comment: [Wayback Machine](https://archive.org/web/)?

Comment: @AlE. might not be very accurate

Answer (score 2):

YouTube does not display the date when a video was deleted anywhere publicly, neither on the website nor on the API. You may get a general idea of when it's been deleted by looking at the wayback machine or by googling the videoID (the part after `watch?v=`), but you you won't find an exact timestamp.